# Adding a increment value in column in R

Tags: r

[image]

I need to add a value next to name for example in image Ashish 1. I want to add a value like 1,2 3,4,5. there are 500 enteries in total

I used this code to change first 20 but i want to change it for all 500

```
customer$name[1:10] = names

names=c('Ashish1','Alok1','Ricky1','Sagar1','Meet1','Sameer1','Surbhi1','Yash1','Sandeep1','Mohsin1')
customer$name[11:20] = names
```

Please execuse still not use to add things properly.

Comment: Please make it easier for people who are trying to help you. Don’t add data/code as images. Provide a reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to increment every duplicate? Such that `c("Ashish","Ricky","Sagar","Ashish","Sagar","Ashish","Ricky")` gets changed to `c("Ashish1","Ricky1","Sagar1","Ashish2","Sagar2","Ashish3","Ricky2")`?

I've opted to increase *all* customer names (is there a reason only the very first should not be added an incremented value?) simply because it's easier. But I will show that once we can do that, it is easy to only add to every subsequent:

Introducing the package `dplyr`:

```
customer %>% group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(i = 1:n()) %>% ungroup %>%
  mutate(name = paste0(name, i)
```

If you have any ordering to determine which name is the "first", e.g. `customerId`, add `arrange(customerId) %>%` after the first `group_by`.

Now that we have added an increasing number, let's modify it, so the very first is not modified:

```
customer %>% group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(i = 1:n()) %>% ungroup %>%
  mutate(name = ifelse(i > 1, paste0(name, i), name))
```

Comment: If this answer solved your issue, please consider giving it an upvote and mark it as answered.